# Nested ParameterGroups in AWS CloudFormation?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

Is it possible to have nested Parametergroups in AWS CloudFormation script, for example I would like to have one parameter group for network configuration and within that groups various subgroups for VPC, Public Subnet, Private Subnet, Internet Gateway etc.

```
"Metadata" : {
    "AWS::CloudFormation::Interface" : {
      "ParameterGroups" : [
        {
          "Label" : { "default" : "Network Configuration" },
          "Parameters" : [ 
            {   “Label” : {“default” : “VPC Details”},
                “Parameters” : [“VPCName", "VPCCIDR”]
            },
            {   “Label” : {“default” : Public subnet details”},
                “Parameters” : [ "PublicSubnetName", "PublicSubnetCIDR", "PublicSubnetAZ”]
            },
            {   “Label” : {“default” : “Private Subnet Details”},
                “Parameters” : [ "PrivateSubnetName", "PrivateSubnetCIDR", "PrivateSubnetAZ”]
            }
         ]
        }
      ]
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

In accordance with the [official documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-cloudformation-interface-parametergroup.html), AWS CloudFormation Interface ParameterGroup doesn't offer nested capability.

I am using a grouping naming like:

Mainpoint - subpoint 1

Mainpoint - subpoint 2

so I'd suggest that to you too.